# Select value in selectbox depending on first selection in other selectbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select a value in a selectbox, after a value was chosen in the first selectbox. Now I'm just replacing the whole selectbox, but they are styled using javascript, that calls some css, so I'm trying to avoid using 'eval()'; and just changing the select option.

In the first selectbox, the user selects a product. After that, a query should find an appending number, that has to do with billing, and that number must be automatically selected in the second selectbox. But they must be able to change it, so it must be a selectbox, not just a textbox.

Help?

Comment: provide some code with wat uve tried please.

Comment: I only tried to change the whole HTML with Ajax, for the whole checkbox. I'm not that familiar with Javascript, and I searched, but could not find a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demo here http://jsbin.com/adidus/1/edit

Hope this can give you a suggestion :)

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I'll just have to add some php-and mysql-code, but I'm able to do that. Thanks a lot!